# How to use Observer pattern in java?

Tags: java

I am a student and this question revolves around some code for my homework. I have tried to do it and I have included my answer in here as well. I'd really appreciate as much help as I can get. How can I use observer pattern to  write a separate class, ScrollDown, to take care of scrolling to the bottom of the pane after every time we append something to "status" in the OurGame class with the ScrollDown object being the observer and the OurGame object being observed.

```
/* This class implements a game and outputs the current game information to a
 * JTextArea in a JScrollPane in a JFrame. 
 */
public class OurGame
{
  private JTextArea status; // text area to print game status

  /** Constructs a new game and sets up the basic GUI. */
  public OurGame()
  {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Our Game"); // create frame
    status = new JTextArea(25,20); // create JTextArea
    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(status); // put status in a scroll pane
    frame.getContentPane().add(pane); // put pane in the JFrame's contentPane
    frame.pack(); // pack the frame
    frame.setVisible(true); // make it visible
  }

  /**
  * Get the current JTextArea. Hint: Invoke this method from ScrollDown.
  * @return The game's JTextArea
  */
  public JTextArea getStatus()
  {
    return status;
  }

  /** prints the game information in the GUI using toString(). */
  public void print()
  {
    status.append(toString());
  }

  /* other methods, e.g. toString() omitted. */
  . . .
}
```

Here is one way to scroll down to the bottom of the scroll pane:

```
status.setCaretPosition(status.getDocument().getLength());
```

The ScrollDown object will be notified when information is appended to the JFrame so that it can do the appropriate scrolling.

You are to write only the changed portions of the OurGame class above (use ". . ." as appropriate for the parts that are unchanged), plus the entire ScrollDown class. For full marks, explanatory comments are required. You must explain your changes to OurGame, and Javadoc comments are required for ScrollDown.

My solution is:

```
// changes to OurGame
import java.util.Observable;
public class OurGame extends Observable
{
  ... //unchanged
  // part to be changed in this classic only the print method
  public void print()
  {
    status.append(toString());
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers(status.getDocument().getLength());
  }
}

//ScrollDown class
import java.util.Observer;
public class ScrollDown implements Observer
{
  public void update(Observer a, Object position)
  {
    status.setCaretPosition((int)position);
  }
}
```

Please I'd really appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Ask it like how please?

Comment: Like a normal, English question, ending with a question mark. "I'd appreciate any halp" is not a question. We need some concrete question, forcused on something precise, that we can answer with a concrete answer.

Comment: In the form of a question. What are you looking for? Is something wrong with your solution?

Comment: oh okay.. I've done that. I hope its better now

Comment: @JBNizet "How can I use observer pattern to write a separate class, ScrollDown, to take care of scrolling to the bottom of the pane after every time we append something to "status" in the OurGame class with the ScrollDown object being the observer and the OurGame object being observed.". It doesn't have a question mark I ll give u that....

Comment: @PaulErlenmeyer my comment was posted *before* the OP added that part. It was added *because* I posted that comment.

Comment: so can anyone please help with the question?

Comment: @JBNizet Alright I see :)